# Relating an integral of to a PDF of a known distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am facing some difficulties in relating the following integral into a PDF of a known distribution.
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} ye^{-y(x+1)} \,dy $$

I am aware that this can be transformed into the gamma distribution, but how can I go about relating the two? Evaluating this integral otherwise takes way too much time. Are there any kind of tricks one can use to spot such occurrences?

Comment: This is link to the mean of exponential distribution with parameter $x+1$. The result should be $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$

Comment: The substitution $z=y(x+1)$ converts this integral into $(x+1)^{-2} \int_0^{\infty} z e^{-z}\,dz$. So what remains is to verify that $\int_0^\infty ze^{-z}\,dz=1$.